# Prove the following integral is less than 1.

Tags: calculus

Need help proving that $\int_0^1 (x\tan{\frac{\pi{x^3}}{4}})^{27}dx \leq 1$. I have tried showing that function was bounded by the integral bounds.

Comment: Can you find a simple bound on the integrand?

Comment: Notice that the integrand is 0 at x = 0, and it is 1 at x = 1.

Comment: Just show that $(x\tan \frac{\pi x^3}{4})^{27} \le 1$ when $0\le x \le 1$.

Comment: @choco_addicted It is the sum of all x between 0 and 1 .Therefore , that is not enough

Comment: @Leth If $f (x) \le g (x) $, then $\int_a^b f (x)dx \le \int_a^b g (x)dx $. Thus it is enough.

Comment: You are  right..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:**

Note that for $0\le x\le \pi/4$, $\tan(x)\le 1$.